# How to avoid C thread blocking by a child process opened with io.popen from lua?

Tags: c, lua, pthreads, sh, popen

I have a C pthread running a non-blocking event loop which executes lua scripts. A lua script runs io.popen to execute a shell script which takes some time to complete.
I am only interested in capturing the first few characters from the output of the script even though the script takes time to complete. As the lua script reads those first few characters and reaches its end it returns execution to C as expected. The problem is that the shell script that was opened with io.popen keeps running in the background until it completes. Calling f.close() in lua after reading the first few characters does not seem to halt its execution (it appears to only close the read side of the pipe?).  Unfortunately, it starts blocking my C thread and displays "write error: broken pipe" messages until the shell script ends. This would make sense if the read end of the pipe is closed (and garbage collected) as the lua script ends execution, and the write end is still being written to by the shell script. The question is, how do I either kill the shell script since i am no longer interested in the rest of its output/execution, or silence it in a way that will not block my parent process?

I have tried redirecting 2>/dev/null on the io.popen command but that only silenced the "write error: broken pipe" messages - the blocking is still there.
If there is a way to get the child process (from C) of what lua openes with io.popen and kill that? (I'm thinking that might also help).

Any thoughts/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post your code. It should have your C code, lua script, and the shell script. Most likely, the shell script doesn't [try to] stop writing upon an error. So, for example, if the lua script read just 3 lines, but the shell script wanted to output 10 lines, you'd probably see 7 error messages. You may need to fix the shell script but we can't tell for sure unless we see the code.

Comment: More information is required. Specifically, a [mre].  I can completely believe that the script in question complains about a broken pipe, but it is somewhat surprising that it does not terminate when it first encounters that.  More importantly, it's unclear by what mechanism any thread in the parent process might be blocked.

Comment: Have you tried having the lua script use another io.popen to issue a SIGKILL to the script it forked earlier?

Comment: @kprow - that works, thank you for suggesting that! i used pkill -f script_name and no more blocking/broken pipe messages! There is no other way to do it from C I suppose to somehow kill it when the lua script completes?

Comment: When a process on a unixy system writes to a closed pipe, they are sent the SIGPIPE signal. By default, this would kill the writing process. This particular program is ignoring SIGPIPE, as evidenced by the fact that it's displaying an error message instead of getting killed. It seems the program created your problem intentionally. It would be up to you send it a signal that does kill it (SIGTERM?), or one that definitely does in the most impolite way (SIGKILL).

Comment: Or maybe you're not on a unixy system. The write would simply fail on Windows as if SIGPIPE was being ignored in a unixy system. There is a system call that force a Windows program to exit

Comment: @ikegami thank you for the big clue here, yes I believe I am ignoring SIGPIPE in the parent before I create the pthread, so I need to look into that.

Comment: Its whether SIGPIPE is being ignored in the child that matters, but the child might be inheriting the setting from the parent